# MySQL: One To Many Combinations

Tags: mysql

Below is the table data (Order_audit)

```
+------------+-----------------+
|   OrderID  |  shipping_type  |
+------------+-----------------+
|   W1       |   0             |
|   W1       |   2             |
|   W2       |   2             |
|   W3       |   2             |
|   W3       |   2             |
|   W3       |   1             |
|   W4       |   0             |
|   W5       |   1             |
|   W5       |   2             |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I want sql to extract orderID having shipping_type with combinations of (0 or 1) and 2. In this example W1,W3,W5 are orders which fall in this criteria.
Assuming Table Name is order_audit.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Surely `W3` and `W4` are the records that fail your criteria? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a154d/5

Comment: W2 and W4 shouldn't get in result

Comment: Yes, so `W1`, `W2` and `W5` should?

Comment: yes, It should be part of result

Answer (score 1):

We can try aggregating by `OrderID` and then asserting the following two conditions on each order group:

- There are two (and only two) distinct `shipping_type` values present
- One of those `shipping_type` values is 2

If both of the above conditions are true, it would imply that the order had either `(0, 2)` or `(1, 2)` as shipping combinations.

```
SELECT OrderID
FROM yourTable
WHERE shipping_type IN (0, 1, 2)
GROUP BY OrderID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT shipping_type) = 2 AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN shipping_type = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```

### Demo

Comment: @Nick Good catch.  I missed that.

Comment: No worries. Always better for OP to have a choice of answers.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be with this query which looks for all orders which have a `shipping_type` of 0 or 1 and have a matching entry with a `shipping_type` of 2.

```
SELECT OrderID
FROM order_audit a1
WHERE shipping_type IN(0,1) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM order_audit a2
            WHERE a2.OrderID = a1.OrderID AND shipping_type = 2)
```

### Demo

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for adding the demo I'm on my phone so a bit hard.

Comment: Use Rextester if on a mobile phone; SQLFiddle from mobile is total nightmare.  But, Rextester was down today, last time I checked :-(

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the tip I haven't tried rextester on mobile.

Comment: Wow...Thanks you are savior :D

Comment: No worries. If you used one of the answers (both are good) you should accept it.